# I need to find the least nonnegative residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I have a hard time finding the least non negative residue of large numbers, and I'm having trouble with finding the least non negative residue of (1511)^7 (mod 3131) can someone help?

Comment: [Wolframalpha is always happy to help](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1511)%5E7+mod+3131).  Doing it by hand would be horribly tedious.  If you must do it by hand, then perhaps try solving the two problems $1511^7\pmod{31}$ and $1511^7\pmod{101}$ separately and combine the results via chinese remainder.

Comment: It's not that tedious by hand, and helps cement the techniques of the Chinese remainder theorem (as you mention), and Fermat's little theorem/Euler's theorem, and the repeated squaring algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prime decomposition of the modulus: $\;3131=31\cdot 101$.

   2. *Bézout's relation* between $31$ and $101$ with the *extended Euclidean algorithm*:
      $$\begin{array}[t]{rrrrr}
      \text{Successive Divisions}& r_i & u_i & v_i & q_i\\
           \hline
       & 101 & 1 & 0 & \\
      101= {\color{red}3} \times 31 +\color{blue}{8} & 31 & 0 & 1 & \color{red}{3} \\
      \hline
          31 = {\color{red}3} \times 8 + \color{blue}{7} & \color{blue}{8} & 1 & -3 & \color{red}3 \\
          8 = {\color{red}1} \times 7 + \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{7} & -3 & 10 & \color{red}1 \\
        & \color{blue}{1} & 4 & -13 \\
           \hline
          \end{array}$$
      Thus, $\;4\times 101-13\times31=1$.
   3. Reducing $1511$ modulo $31$ and modulo $101$:
      $$1511\bmod 31=-8,\quad 1511\bmod101=-4.$$
   4. Powers mod $31$ and mod $101$, with the *fast exponentiation algorithm*:
      $$\begin{array}{ccr}
      n&S& P\\
      \hline
      7&-8&-8\\
      3&2&2\cdot-8=15\\
      1&4&4\cdot15=\color{red}{-2}\\
      \hline
      \end{array}
      \qquad\begin{array}{cr}
      S&P\\
      \hline
      -4&-4\\
      16&16\cdot(-4)=37\\
      54&54\cdot 37=\color{red}{-22}\\
      \hline
      \end{array}$$
   5. Thus $1511^7=-2\bmod31$ and $1511^7=-22\bmod101$, so that
      \begin{align*}1511^7&=-2\times 4\times101+22\times13\times31\\&=-2\times404+22\times403=20\times403-2\\&=8058\bmod3131,
      \end{align*}
      and the least non-negative integer of $1511^7\mod3131$ is $\;\color{red}{1796}$.